# 3rd and 4th scanf not taking input

Tags: c, input, scanf

I'm trying to enter input into an array via `scanf()`.  The 1st and 2nd `scanf()` calls seem to work as I expect.  The other two don't work, and I can't figure out why.  Can anyone point out the problem?

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define SIZE_A (10)
#define SIZE_B (10)
#define SIZE_C (SIZE_A+SIZE_B)

int main()
{
    int A[SIZE_A] = {0}, B[SIZE_B] = {0};
    int A_input = 0, B_input = 0;

    printf("First series length:\n");
    scanf("%d", &A_input);
    printf("Enter %d numbers for first series:\n", A_input);
    scanf("%d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d", &A[0], &A[1], &A[2], &A[3], &A[4],
            &A[5], &A[6], &A[7], &A[8], &A[9]);
    {
        printf("Second series length:\n");
        scanf("%d",&B_input); /* problem here */
        printf("Enter %d numbers for second series:\n", B_input);
        scanf("%d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d", &B[0], &B[1], &B[2], &B[3], &B[4],
                &B[5], &B[6], &B[7], &B[8], &B[9]); /* problem here */
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Err... why have you asked for the series' lengths and then totally ignored them? You can't discard any unused entry fields, the first series entry will not be satisfied until you enter 10 values. It's no use hitting `enter` after say 5 entries and thinking the code will move on to the second series. `enter` is just whitespace, as is `space` and so on.

Comment: at first, i thought i would use them to determine the array size, tho i saw that it has to be const ill use it later for the rest of the code

Comment: Please describe the behaviour of your program more specifically than "it doesn't work". In particular, what was the exact input and what was the observed behaviour of your program for those inputs?

Comment: Use the series length for a loop, each iteration asking for one value. And do check the return value from `scanf()`. And do check each series length is `<= 10`. You are the only one who can protect you own code in C.

Comment: As @WeatherVane says, the program will not work as you seem to want unless you provide exactly ten numbers in each series.  If that does not explain the problem, then do present the input you are using, the result you are getting, and why you think that's incorrect.

Comment: i need to create a code that reads 2 series of numbers up to 10 numbers each series. then it makes a third series, a combination of the 1st and second. it has to be exactly like that (user picks values) `First series length:
5
Enter 5 numbers for first series:
1 8 9 23 -32
Second series length:
3
Enter 3 numbers for second series:
90 23 6 
new series: 1 90 8 23 9 6 23 -32`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have corrected your code to input the requested number of values, hope it helps you.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define SIZE_A (10)
#define SIZE_B (10)
#define SIZE_C (SIZE_A+SIZE_B)

int main()
{
    int A[SIZE_A] = {0}, B[SIZE_B] = {0};
    int A_input = 0, B_input = 0;
    int i;

    printf("First series length:\n");
    if (scanf("%d", &A_input) != 1)
        exit(1);
    if (A_input < 1 || A_input > SIZE_A)
        exit(1);
    printf("Enter %d numbers for first series:\n", A_input);
    for (i=0; i<A_input; i++)
        if (scanf("%d", &A[i]) != 1)
            exit(1);

    printf("Second series length:\n");
    if (scanf("%d", &B_input) != 1)
        exit(1);
    if (B_input < 1 || B_input > SIZE_B)
        exit(1);
    printf("Enter %d numbers for second series:\n", B_input);
    for (i=0; i<B_input; i++)
        if (scanf("%d", &B[i]) != 1)
            exit(1);

    return 0;
}
```

Program session:

```
First series length:
3
Enter 3 numbers for first series:
1 2 3
Second series length:
4
Enter 4 numbers for second series:
7 8 9 10
```

Comment: I have not solved your additional question posted in comment about combining the two arrays. You'll need to attempt that yourself, please.

Comment: Thx Weather, but there's a reason I haven't used a loop to scan the input. the input for each series has to be in one line for example: 10 20 30 40... when i use a loop it continusly asks for input. I hope my problem is now clear and OFC please dont i need to do that myself, just that step is a problem for me, getting the input the way they want it

Comment: @lior it does not matter whether the inputs are all on one line with a space between each, or on separate lines with a newline between each - all are whitespace. You only need an `enter` after the last entry of each series. Please try it.

Comment: @lior I added sample input session.

Comment: OMG, ok now i see where my problem was. I shouldn't fall asleep in class.

Comment: Thanks Weather, that helped me understand whitespaces which i did not understand before